# Azure debug console terminates on "composer.phar"

Tags: debugging, laravel, azure, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I managed to install composer on a web app on Azure. However, when I try to run it the debug console I'm terminated:

[image: Writing composer.phar in terminal terminates me]

I can run php artisan serve, but I get no feedback from the terminal. As shown in the screenshot, I am in the folder where the artisan file is:

[image]

I'm missing something, does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing is that the composer extension builds apps automatically. The problem has been solved, excuse me.